# BeautifulSoup page number

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract text from the online version of [The Wealth of Nations](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/38194/38194-h/38194-h.htm#BOOK_I) and create a data frame where each observation is a page of the book.  I do it in a roundabout way, trying to imitate something similar I did in R, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this directly in BeautifulSoup.

What I do is first get the entire text from the page:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
r = requests.get('https://www.gutenberg.org/files/38194/38194-h/38194-h.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

But from here on, I'm just working with regular expressions and the text. I find the beginning and end of the book text:

```
beginning = [a.start() for a in re.finditer(r"BOOK I\.",soup.text)]
beginning
end = [a.start() for a in re.finditer(r"FOOTNOTES",soup.text)]
book = soup.text[beginning[1]:end[0]]
```

Then I remove the carriage returns and new lines and split on strings of the form "[Pg digits]" and put everything into a pandas data frame.

```
book = book.replace('\r',' ').replace('\n',' ')
l = re.compile('\[[P|p]g\s?\d{1,3}\]').split(book)
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['col1'])
df['page'] = range(2,df.shape[0]+2)
```

There are indicators in the HTML code for page numbers of the form `<span class='pagenum'><a name="Page_vii" id="Page_vii">[Pg vii]</a></span>`. Is there a way I can do the text extraction in BeautifulSoup by searching for text between these "spans"? I know how to search for the page markers using findall, but I was wondering how I can extract text between those markers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the page markers and the text associated with it, you can use `bs4` with `re`. In order to match text between two markers, `itertools.groupby` can be used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import re
import itertools
page_data = requests.get('https://www.gutenberg.org/files/38194/38194-h/38194-h.htm').text
final_data = [(i.find('a', {'name':re.compile('Page_\w+')}), i.text) for i in soup(page_data, 'html.parser').find_all('p')]
new_data = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(final_data, key=lambda x:bool(x[0]))][1:]
final_data = {new_data[i][0][0].text:'\n'.join(c for _, c in new_data[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(new_data), 2)}
```

Output (**Sample, the actual result is too long for SO format**):

```
{'[Pg vi]': "'In recompense for so many mortifying things, which nothing but truth\r\ncould have extorted from me, and which I could easily have multiplied to a\r\ngreater number, I doubt not but you are so good a christian as to return good\r\nfor evil, and to flatter my vanity, by telling me, that all the godly in Scotland\r\nabuse me for my account of John Knox and the reformation.'\nMr. Smith having completed, and given to the world his system of\r\nethics, that subject afterwards occupied but a small part of his lectures.\r\nHis attention was now chiefly directed to the illustration of\r\nthose other branches of science which he taught; and, accordingly, he\r\nseems to have taken up the resolution, even at that early period, of\r\npublishing an investigation into the principles of what he considered\r\nto be the only other branch of Moral Philosophy,—Jurisprudence, the\r\nsubject of which formed the third division of his lectures. At the\r\nconclusion of the Theory of Moral Sentiments, after treating of the\r\nimportance of a system of Natural Jurisprudence, and remarking that\r\nGrotius was the first, and perhaps the only writer, who had given any\r\nthing like a system of those principles which ought to run through,\r\nand be the foundation of the law of nations, Mr. Smith promised, in\r\nanother discourse, to give an account of the general principles of law\r\nand government, and of the different revolutions they have undergone\r\nin the different ages and periods of society, not only in what concerns\r\njustice, but in what concerns police, revenue, and arms, and whatever\r\nelse is the object of law.\nFour years after the publication of this work, and after a residence\r\nof thirteen years in Glasgow, Mr. Smith, in 1763, was induced to relinquish\r\nhis professorship, by an invitation from the Hon. Mr. Townsend,\r\nwho had married the Duchess of Buccleugh, to accompany the\r\nyoung Duke, her son, in his travels. Being indebted for this invitation\r\nto his own talents alone, it must have appeared peculiarly flattering\r\nto him. Such an appointment was, besides, the more acceptable,\r\nas it afforded him a better opportunity of becoming acquainted with\r\nthe internal policy of other states, and of completing that system of\r\npolitical economy, the principles of which he had previously delivered\r\nin his lectures, and which it was then the leading object of his studies\r\nto perfect.\nMr. Smith did not, however, resign his professorship till the day\r\nafter his arrival in Paris, in February 1764. He then addressed the\r\nfollowing letter to the Right Honourable Thomas Millar, lord advocate\r\nof Scotland, and then rector of the college of Glasgow:—", '[Pg vii]': "His lordship having transmitted the above to the professors, a meeting\r\nwas held; on which occasion the following honourable testimony\r\nof the sense they entertained of the worth of their former colleague\r\nwas entered in their minutes:—\n'The meeting accept of Dr. Smith's resignation in terms of the above letter;\r\nand the office of professor of moral philosophy in this university is therefore\r\nhereby declared to be vacant. The university at the same time, cannot\r\nhelp expressing their sincere regret at the removal of Dr. Smith, whose distinguished\r\nprobity and amiable qualities procured him the esteem and affection\r\nof his colleagues; whose uncommon genius, great abilities, and extensive\r\nlearning, did so much honour to this society. His elegant and ingenious\r\nTheory of Moral Sentiments having recommended him to the esteem of men\r\nof taste and literature throughout Europe, his happy talents in illustrating\r\nabstracted subjects, and faithful assiduity in communicating useful knowledge,\r\ndistinguished him as a professor, and at once afforded the greatest pleasure,\r\nand the most important instruction, to the youth under his care.'\nIn the first visit that Mr. Smith and his noble pupil made to Paris,\r\nthey only remained ten or twelve days; after which, they proceeded\r\nto Thoulouse, where, during a residence of eighteen months, Mr. Smith\r\nhad an opportunity of extending his information concerning the internal\r\npolicy of France, by the intimacy in which he lived with some of\r\nthe members of the parliament. After visiting several other places in\r\nthe south of France, and residing two months at Geneva, they returned\r\nabout Christmas to Paris. Here Mr. Smith ranked among his\r\nfriends many of the highest literary characters, among whom were\r\nseveral of the most distinguished of those political philosophers who\r\nwere denominated Economists."}
```

Comment: What I want was not clear in my question, so I've edited it. Basically, it's not the page markers I need as much as I need to extract the text between those markers and assign them a page number. In my example, I have a pandas data frame where one column is text and the other is page number. Each observation is one page of the text.

Comment: @Ajax1234, he wants the text of each page with the corresponding page number. Not the text inside the page tag.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Thank you for the clarification. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. Page vii should begin with "fore, I do resign my office of professor of moral philosophy in the university of
Glasgow, and in the college thereof, with all the emoluments, privileges, and." I think this is picking up text at the beginning of the paragraph and ending at the end of the paragraph whenever it finds "Page_ " in the paragraph block.

Comment: @user21359 The goal of the algorithm is to start at the beginning of the paragraph and storing the text until the end of the paragraph. Gutenburg  structures the page numbers next to each paragraph. Once the text is extracted from the the page markers, which page marker is the key? The top marker or the bottom?

Comment: I assume that everything that lies between markers belongs to the page indicated by the top marker.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance; I will have to look at this later, but there is still a problem. What is marked as page 93 "In all new colonies, the great quantity..." is actually well into page 94. Moreover, page vi should start with "a view of talking with him." I wonder if it's not easier to just throw all the book text into a long string and extract what is needed, rather than using bs.

Comment: @user21359: Glad to help. Your latter idea may be the best, as your goal in general is achievable, although I do not think the text is uniform enough. I posted the solution above because it worked for all cases that I found, however, there are still outliers, as you pointed out.